# Can we WITH x AS ( ... ) INSERT INTO y(k) SELECT * FROM x in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

We [can](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) do `INSERT INTO SELECT`, but what if I have a bunch of `WITH AS` statements (about 27ish) for the `SELECT` part? My current solution is do the query then scan using programming language (`Golang` for my case) then insert it using normal `INSERT INTO` statement one by one. Was there one step solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
insert into item
  with x as (    
    select id + 10 as id1, concat(brand,' D') as brand1 from item),
       y as (    
    select id + 20 as id1, concat(brand,' E') as brand1 from item)  
  select * from x   
  union all   
  select * from y
```

Yes, we can!

Answer (score 2):

Ir is not permited to have more than one WITH at one level

you can only use subqueries

```
INSERT INTO testable WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

But you can use With clause at different Levels like

```
INSERT INTO testtabe WITH cte1 AS (SELECT 1)
SELECT * FROM (WITH cte2 AS (SELECT 2) SELECT * FROM cte2 JOIN cte1) AS dt;
```